# android net::ERROR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, browser, https

In the app call android System browser to open https link,it first open the link but quickly shut and show :

The web page at `app://getLocalAppVersion` could not be loaded because:

> net::ERROR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

The phone I use is Huawei,is anyone here could help me? Many thanks!

Comment: I think you should post your code here to let use know how you call that link. This error happens when android does not know which app will handle that type of scheme, in your case is "app://"

Comment: Thanks man,the root cause is the certification of this website has expired.it's ok,now.